# How to find functions in IDA Pro/x64dbg

Tags: ida, disassembly, ollydbg, debuggers, dynamic-analysis

i created a program for testing, very simple in c++.
is ask for password if it is match is print correct, if no it is print "bad".

i try to find with ida where is the function of what i made.

but i can find it only with the strings.

there is a different way to find it?, i mean not by the string?
maybe with the debugger step by step? or something else?
because in other programs i don't have strings, and its hard for me to find function.

Answer (score 0):

There are a couple of ways to find the main() function. In IDA you can set the debugger to break on the entry point. This is sometimes not the main() function, but if you break there you can single-step until you reach the main function. You can also often find main() in the list of functions in IDA because main is one of the symbols. This is probably the simplest way to identify the function but it sounds like that is not working for you.

Comment: i tried to break the in the entry point, and i did step by step with the debugger, but he didn't reach to the main(). you have more tricks?

Comment: What compiler did you use? Is this a windowed application? Also, what OS?

Comment: visual studio 2017

Comment: and windows 10.